# Samba client - unix username differ from smb

Tags: linux, samba, thunar

Problem: Can't map unix user to smb username on client.

Scenario:

```
server1 running Windows with smb shares
client1 running Debian

On server1 is user JSmith
On client1 is user jsm
```

When trying to browse shares from client1 the user have to be specified as JSmith in order to connect.
When using thunar the unix username is used for smb discovery which leads to failure.

Is there way to override this behavior.

Comment: You could just not use Thunar and manually mount the shares instead.

Comment: At this time I am already doing this